# Не работает file_get_contents на https

Tags: php, file-get-contents

есть файл get_data.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
if ( isSet($_POST['url']) ) {
  if( true == ($str=file_get_contents( $_POST['url'] ) )) {
    echo $str;
    exit;
  }
} 
echo "could not read page"; 
?>
```

суть файла, отображает стили другого сайта, и отображает на ACE. На локалхосте всё хорошо отлично работает, на сайте отображает could not read page. Сайт на https://
Может есть идеи, помогите пожалуйста

[image: Версия PHP]
Вот что отображается на моём php

Comment: почему именно решили что не работает file_get_contents? у вас 2 условия!

Comment: Какой из них лишний? Подскажите

Comment: 1 условие проверяет переменную в POST запросе, а если её там нет? 2 условие чтение содержимого из файла, а если относительный или полный путь до файла на твоем сервере не существует?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, Ваш сервер не поддерживает ssl

Либо настройте эту поддержку, либо используйте curl

Подробнее о curl в Вашем случае [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https)